# Can I download Ubuntu 12.04 on a notebook/laptop?

Tags: system-installation

I am downloading Ubuntu 12.04.3-desktop. Is this the correct file to use for notebook computers? If yes, why not label it as such?  If no, what version should I use for my notebook?

Answer (score 1):

The designation of *"Desktop Edition"* in this case isn't meant in contrast to *"Laptop"*, but in contrast to *"Server Edition"*.

Answer (score 0):

you can install desktop versions on laptops as well. I would use 12.04 LTS because of Long Term Support.

> For extended support, choose Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
>
> Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS is a long-term support release. It has continuous
>   hardware support improvements as well as guaranteed security and
>   support updates until April 2017.

download [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts)

The installation instruction [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support)